# How would I extract the second lowest value of a particular column of a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

```
var rowText = $('tbody tr:eq(2) td:eq(2)').map(function() {
return $(this).text();
}).get()[0];

window.alert(rowText);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pcxx9dyy/2/

I'm specifically looking to extract the lowest price on the marketplace of an item excluding the NPC's one.

The rows are always sorted, but sometimes there are zero NPC Shop records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this table is always sorted INCR and first row always has NPC Shop records, then just fix your code like that:

```
$('tbody tr:eq(2) td:eq(1)')
```

And it works.
But if rows can be unsorted, and there might be more than one, or even zero NPC Shop records, then you need more complex algo.

**Update**

Here is the code for "unsorted" and "any number of NPC shop records": [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcxx9dyy/4/)

Code:

```
var price = null;
$("tbody tr").each(function(i,e){
    var $col1 = $(e).find("td:eq(0)"),$col2 = $(e).find("td:eq(1)");
    if ($col1.html().indexOf("NPC")===-1) {
        var rowPrice = parseFloat($col2.html().replace(",","."));
        if (!price || price.price>rowPrice)
            price = {
                name:$col1.find("a").html(),
                price: rowPrice
            };
    }
});

alert("Min price is:"+price.price+" from "+price.name);
```

Comment: The rows are always sorted, but sometimes there are zero NPC Shop records.

Comment: It works! The only problem is when I visit the actual webpage and the script just seems not to load with this snippet of code in it.                               <script src="http://img.subeta.net/scripts.js?new=81" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: You might need to wait for DOM (html) to be fully loaded and generated before running the script?

Comment: Yeah, that might work, but I prefer other "domReady" shortcut, provided by jQuery, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pcxx9dyy/7/

Comment: Also, it seem that you have exception in external script, that you've connected to JSFiddle example. It starts working if I remove it

Comment: Any way I can prevent it from loading or something? I'm using the script on Tampermonkey, browser-side/client upon loading the webpage. Maybe a finally, catch, or document.rewrite with regex? I'm not sure.

Comment: Sorry, this question out of your initial question's and my knowledge scopes :(